# $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ are linear function such that $\forall x$, $f(g(x))$ and $g(f(x))$ are identity functions. Compute $f(2006)$

Tags: functions, systems-of-equations

$f(x)$ and $g(x)$ are linear functions such that $\forall x$, $f(g(x))$ and $g(f(x))$ are identity functions. If $f(0)=4$ and $g(5)=17$, compute $f(2006)$

My attempt is as follows:-

If $f(g(x))$ is the identity function then $g(x)$ needs to be identity function because otherwise if $g(x)$ is not defined for any $x$, then $f(g(x))$ will also not be defined for that $x$.

Same logic goes with $g(f(x))$, hence $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ are identity functions.

Let $f(x)=ax+b, g(x)=cx+d$

$$f(0)=4$$
$$b=4$$

$$g(5)=17$$
$$5c+d=17\tag{1}$$

$$f(g(x))=f(cx+d)$$
$$f(g(x))=a(cx+d)+b$$
$$f(g(x))=acx+ad+b\tag{2}$$

$$g(f(x))=g(ax+b)$$
$$g(f(x))=c(ax+b)+d$$
$$g(f(x))=acx+bc+d\tag{3}$$

Putting $x=5$ in equation $(2)$

$$f(g(5))=5ac+ad+4$$
$$f(17)=5ac+ad+4\tag{4}$$

Putting $x=0$ in the equation $(3)$
$$g(f(0))=4c+d$$
$$g(4)=17-c$$

I am stuck here, not getting any clue. Please help me in this.

Comment: I can't follow your argumentation. $f$ can't be an identity function, because $f(0) = 4$, so function value $\neq$ function argument. Similar for $g$.

Comment: By identity function, I am thinking that the function is defined for all x

Comment: Where did you get that definition from? An [identity function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Identity_function) is usually just a function "that always returns the same value that was used as its argument" (Wikipedia).

Comment: Both $f$ and $g$ are defined for all $x$. You should clarify precisely what you mean by identity function, since "$f(g(x))$ and $g(f(x))$ are identity functions" usually means that $x=g(f(x))=f(g(x))$, i.e. $f$ is the inverse of $g$ and vice-versa.

Answer (score 1):

$$f(x)=ax+b \qquad g = f^{-1}$$

If $f(x)=y$ then $g(y)=g(f(x)) = x$. Hence $g$ is the (left) inverse of $f$. Similarly, if $g(x)=y$, then f(y)= f(g(x)) = x$.

\begin{align}
   f(0)  &= 4 \\
   b &= 4 \\
   \hline
   g(5) &= 17 \\
   f(17) &= 5 \\
   17a + 4 &= 5 \\
   a &= \dfrac{1}{17} \\
   \hline
   f(x) &= \dfrac{1}{17}x + 4 \\
   f(2006) &= \dfrac{2006}{17} + 4 \\
   f(2006) &= 122
\end{align}

Comment: can you tell me how you said that f is the inverse of g or vice versa

Comment: You have a typo: $17a+4=5$ implies $17a=1$, not $-1$.